# JavaScript equivalent of :perldo?

Tags: command-line

Is there a JavaScript equivalent of `:perldo` that allows writing one-liners that perform inline replacement of the file (or file lines) based on small, ad hoc JavaScript programs?

For example, this hypothetical code would change all double quotes to single quotes:

```
:jsdo replace(/"/g, "'")
```

Or here's a command to convert snake_case to camelCase:

```
:jsdo replace(/_([\w])/g, (_, ch) => ch.toUpperCase())
```

Start each line with the line number:

```
:jsdo split('\n').map((line, i) => `${i+1} ${line}`).join('\n')
```

I know all of these things can be done with Perl or Ruby. But I'm looking to be able to use my existing experience with JavaScript rather than learning another language.

Comment: Short answer: No there is no javascript equivalent and if you really want that you'll have to implement it yourself which is not trivial. I think the reason it doesn't exists is that one of the core feature of perl is that it was created with text manipulation in mind whereas javascript doesn't particularly shine when it comes to this topic. While I understand that you want to reuse your js skills you'll most probably get much more efficient with vim if you learn a bit of vimscript. Maybe you should consider asking directly how to do what you intend to do and you'll get a better answer.

Comment: For example the replace command in your examples would be quite easy to make with built-in `:s` or `:g` commands.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I use `:s` often. For simple cases this is good enough. I wanted JS for more involved examples. I don't know about `:g`, will have to investigate.